# Can I "name" a filter and refer to it as a scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'd like to do something like this.  The use case is I am showing a table with a configurable set of columns, each of which may have a filter associated with it.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2s5Lc9ej/).

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{money | filterStr}}
  </div>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.money = 33;
    $scope.filterStr = 'currency:"USD$"';
}
```

So as you can see, I basically want to store the filter string text as a scope variable, and then refer to it in the html by its name.  This doesn't work, but is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how filters are supposed to work. Besides, there's already a [currency filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)  built into Angular which does this.

Comment: Currency was just a simple example - the point is that in my html, I don't know what's going to be in an array that I'm iterating over, so I don't know what filter to apply.  Essentially I want to iterate over an array of objects that look like: (value, filterToApplyInView), and print the value formatted by its associated filter.  Basically, is there any way to not hardcode the filter string in the html?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely needed to save a reference to the filter dynamically within your controller $scope, you could create a reference to the filter function within a controller variable and then call it in the HTML like you would any other function or you could run the filter on your data in your controller and save the output to a variable.  Here are two examples of doing this with the currency filter (JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4f9yroq/1/)):

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{ moneyWithFilter }}
      {{ currencyFilter(money, "USD$") }}
  </div>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope, currencyFilter) {
    $scope.money = 33;
    $scope.moneyWithFilter = currencyFilter($scope.money, "USD$");
    $scope.currencyFilter = currencyFilter;
}
```

Notice that you have to append the string 'Filter' to the desired filter in order to inject it into your controller.  You can read more about that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this with

```
                <a ng-click="setCurrent(m)">
                    {{m.name}}
                </a>
 <p ng-repeat="L in List | filter:current.name">
        <a ng-click="add(w)">
            {{w.Name}}
        </a>
    </p>
```

Then

```
function setCurrent(m) {
    $scope.current = m;
}
```